# We are (were?) under spam attack

Tags: support, spam

"Processed Meat" already added on **Charcoal HQ** a link to the following Meta SE thread -> https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47205047#47205047

From [rev 5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/316885/5) of [Web Applications is being "flooded" with spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316885/289691)

> Today several accounts were used to post answers that look like
>   legitimate answers but the strange thing is that they include a
>   sequence of numbers, sometimes preceded by `call +1`.
>
> Specifically, the answers copy text from the question to make the
>   answer look somewhat legitimate and insert a (spam) phone number.
>
> This morning I flagged several of them as spam but they are still
>   coming. I'm wondering if they found a way to bypass the anti-spam IP
>   filtering.
>
> It looks that the posts made this morning by using other puppet
>   accounts were already deleted.
>
> Exhibit 1
>
> From https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/121432
>
> > (and thus already fixed; **gmail help :###'###"###**just try again), a local connectivity issue (we can't help with that), or your
> >     browser has an extension that's messing things up (again, we
>
> The common pattern are the numbers which are always the same, with a zero replaced with a uppercase letter O in some examples, the separators between the numbers change.
>
> Exhibit 2
>
> From https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/121435
>
> > all this "allocation" of **call @@###@###@@####**deposits has been done manually by the intern but it takes a lot of time and it is not
> >     very efficient, particularly when an invoice was forgotten in the
> >     past, is added to the table